# How do customize settings.php during installation profile

Tags: distributions, configuration

I'm creating an installation profile for my current company internal project.

During the installation process, one of the custom modules crashes during `init()`, since it tries to use one global variable defined on `settings.php` (that's current default behavior of the module)

Using `system_form_install_settings_form_alter()` I changed the settings form, by adding one input textfield for user's input, and on submit the value is appended to `settings.php`, but `settings.php` is rewrited before profile installation starts.

There is any way to prevent cleanup of `settings.php` by the installation process?

Comment: Maybe it would be easier to patch the module that is crashing, and submit your change to the issue queue for that project.  Before your change is accepted, you can add a reference to your patch in the makefile for your installation profile.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. It's an custom internal module (not a contrib one), but yes, I patched it and problem solved.

Comment: Is it something where using a settings.local.php file that overrides the settings.php file could also help?

Comment: This link was big help for me http://previousnext.com.au/blog/collecting-and-writing-configuration-settings-settingphp-install-profile

Answer (score 3):

You may find it easier to use a `settings.common.php`

Often during team projects, we have local `settings.php` with db credentials etc.. and a `settings.common.php` with settings common to the install and deployment environments.

You can add `settings.common.php` with an include / require line in `settings.php`

```
require 'settings.common.php'; // same directory, e.g sites/default/settings.common.php
```

and then write to it as needed during install.

Answer (score 3):

My answer depends on the server using Apache, but I assume any of the other web servers can accomplish this too.

In your virtualhost config, you can set all of the variables for your environment:

```
SetEnv DBUSER datbase_user
SetEnv DBPASS database_pass
SetEnv DBNAME database_name
SetEnv DBHOST localhost
```

And in your settings.php file:

```
$databases = array (
   'default' => 
   array (
     'default' => 
     array (
       'database' => $_SERVER["DBNAME"],
       'username' => $_SERVER["DBUSER"],
       'password' => $_SERVER["DBPASS"],
       'host' => $_SERVER["DBHOST"],
       'port' => '',
       'driver' => 'mysql',
       'prefix' => '',
    ),
   ),
 );
```

You can set any other variables this way as well.

If you are worried about the $_SERVER array getting into the wrong hands, you can unset all of the important variables at the bottom of settings.php:

```
unset($_SERVER["DBUSER"]);
unset($_SERVER["DBPASS"]);
unset($_SERVER["DBNAME"]);
unset($_SERVER["DBHOST"]);
```

This is how we do it at my office to move sites between our dev environments, staging and even production.